# Принцип работы lambda функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, lambda

Не могу понять, почему данный код возвращает [6,6,6,6], хотя должен возвращать [0,2,4,6].

```
def multipliers():
   return [lambda x: i*x for i in range(4)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка это дубликат, потом кто-нибудь найдёт и укажет на ответ. Но в общем сделайте так, и всё будет правильно работать:

```
def multipliers():
   return [lambda x,i=i: i*x for i in range(4)]
                    ^^^
```

По сути если вы пишете `=` в аргументах лямбды, то вы "захватываете" текущее значение переменной и передаёте его в лямбду. А если так не сделать, то в лямбду попадёт ссылка на переменную, а подставится туда в итоге только последнее значение переменной `i`, а не значение `i` из каждой итерации цикла, как вы хотите.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.